# Beginner Meteor templates

Tags: meteor

This code is from the Meteor first app tutorial, and I am a bit confused about the role of the words "task(s)".

In the html file it is the name of a template, which is called by  `{{> task}}` 
in `<body>`

In the js file, it is used to declare a collection:

`Tasks = new Mongo.Collection("tasks");`
By which is meant "Tasks" is a collection of "tasks"

tasks is also the name of a function in the js file -> `tasks: function ()` 
which returns a list of "tasks" to the html file, where it is called in this way:

```
 {{#each tasks}}
    {{> task}}
  {{/each}}
```

It seems the meaning of "tasks" is both the name of a function, and the data tuples it returns. Is that normal?    Is this statement in `<body>` the template "task" is called to format data returned by a function "tasks" that returns a list of "tasks".  Is that normal?

html file:

```
<body>
<div class="container">
<header>
  <h1>Todo List</h1>
</header>

<ul>
  {{#each tasks}}
    {{> task}}
  {{/each}}
</ul>
</div>
</body>

<template name="task">
<li>{{text}}</li>
</template>
```

js file

```
Tasks = new Mongo.Collection("tasks");

if (Meteor.isClient) {
// This code only runs on the client
  Template.body.helpers({
   tasks: function () {
    return Tasks.find({});
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Agree that the example reuses names, this is quite a common pattern. Perhaps an explanation of each name might help:

```
Tasks = new Mongo.Collection("tasks");
```

- *tasks* on the right-hand-side is the name of the *mongodb* collection. If you go into the mongo shell for example you will see documents in the *db.tasks* collection
- *Tasks* on the left-hand-side is the name of the collection to be used in *javascript* in your Meteor app, both on the client and server. A typical use of *Tasks* will be javascript code such as `Tasks.find({})`

The *tasks* which appears in the *spacebars template code* in your *HTML* file is quite different.

```
{{#each tasks}}
  {{> task}}
{{/each}}
```

- *tasks* refers to a *template helper* function that returns a cursor or array
- *task* refers to an individual *Template* that you've created in HTML. You can tell it's a template because of the template reference `>`

You could replace *tasks* and *task* in your template with *taskList* and *oneTask* and that would be just fine. But you couldn't just start using `MyTasks.find()` in javascript without renaming your `Tasks` collection on the left side of the collection assignment.

There's an unofficial convention that mongo collection names are lower case whereas Meteor collection names (in js) are Proper case. Collection names are global variables in js so the Proper case helps distinguish them anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I can see how that is confusing at first and one may prefer a different naming of variables, functions, helpers and collections to avoid confusion. But yeah, the `> tasks` refers to the template (to be embedded). In the body you need to use `#each tasks` to refer to the helper function (`tasks`). So really there are only three items here:

- `Tasks`, the collection holding the data,
- `tasks`, the helper function that makes data from the `Tasks` collection available to the template engine (referred to in the `body` using `#each tasks`),
- and `task` the template that renders a given task.